# Return data AJAX PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

By defaut, when my system loads some data is filtered in my db and shown to the user. But my doubt is how can I call AJAX to filter some new data, and return it, changing the default values that are already set on my variables.

> This is my AJAX call:

```
 $("#botao-filtrar").click(function(){
  $(".mask-loading").fadeToggle(1000);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'datacenter/functions/filtraDashboardGeral.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {rede: $("#dropdown-parceria").val()},
  })
  .done(function(resposta){
    console.log(resposta);
  })
  .always(function(){
    $(".mask-loading").fadeToggle(1000);
  })
});
```

> And this is what I got from trying to filter some data to return it,
>   but nothing worked:

```
<?php
    require_once('../../includes/conecta.php');

    $rede = $_POST['rede'];

    function buscaDados($conexao){
        $dados = array();

        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM evolucao_originacao WHERE rede = {$rede}");

        while($valores = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
            array_push($dados, $valores);
        }
    }
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: in addition to Zakarias answer, i think you never call the function buscaDados

Comment: Where you are sending the data using `echo`?

Answer (score 1):

You should add `echo` at the end :

```
echo json_encode($dados);
```

So the `$dados` array will be sent back to the ajax request as JSON response.

Parse the response to json uisng `$.parseJSON()` :

```
.done(function(resposta){
     resposta = $.parseJSON(resposta);

     console.log(resposta);
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Zakaria, but how can I use the response on my actual variables? also if i am returning json data, do i need to set the type of data at my ajax code?

Comment: You're welcome, you could parse the data to json in the success callback, check my update.

Answer (score 1):

in your ajax code u add a success.

```
$("#botao-filtrar").click(function(){
  $(".mask-loading").fadeToggle(1000);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'datacenter/functions/filtraDashboardGeral.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {rede: $("#dropdown-parceria").val()},
    success: function (data) {

    //You do not need to use  $.parseJSON(data).  You can immediately process data as array.
    console.log(data)

    //if you have a array you use the following loop

     for (var j =0;j < data.length;j++) {

    console.log(data[j]);
    // u can use data[j] and write to any fields u want.
    // e.g.
    $('.somediv').html(data[j].myarraykey);



     }

  })
  .done(function(resposta){
    console.log(resposta);
  })
  .always(function(){
    $(".mask-loading").fadeToggle(1000);
  })
});
```

And for the php codes (i did not check whether your code is valid or not), you need to add the echo and a die to end the call.

```
$rede = $_POST['rede'];

    $dados = array();

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM evolucao_originacao WHERE rede = {$rede}");

    while($valores = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
        array_push($dados, $valores);
    }
    echo json_encode($dados);
    die();
```

Comment: it return 'null' to my console @dave teu

Comment: can u please add dataType: 'JSON' too and for php code should be echo json_encode  not son_encode (silly autocorrect)

Comment: if it still returns null that means your console.log is working properly, and so is the success call. It's likely your SQL code is returning null results.

Comment: @Dave, i tried your code, but it returns this error https://postimg.org/image/oggrwrqfx/

Comment: Please remove .done codes and .always codes. U can put whatever you want in the success function.

Comment: Well, @someone Special, now its saying that it cant read my data.length because data is null, but my connection is ok and so the query

Comment: @João  can you do try change echo json_encode($dados) to echo json_encode(array('key1'=>1,'key2'=>2));die()   We pass a array and see whether it works.

Comment: but what do i need to put instead of key1, key2 and their values? Im new with it :/

Comment: If the array of key1 and key2 works means your ajax part is completed, and it's likely your php codes for sql query does not return reason. Maybe your sql statement have no results? I use pdo and not mysqli so i'm not an expert but i don't see your declaration for your mysqli connection for variable $conexao